# Why is window "tinting" not window "toning" or "shading"?

Tags: etymology

In color theory, *tinting* means to add white while *toning* adds grey and *shading* adds black. What is the origin of the use of *tinting* then in terms of windows? Are they unrelated?

Comment: Lemme just say that the color theory use of *tinting* (if correct) is, uh, screwy. In the ***real*** world, *tinting* means *adding a touch of color*.

Comment: Color theory does not dictate usage to most English speakers, who are oblivious to the details of its existence. This question appears to be argumentation in disguise.

Comment: Wikipedia:  Meanwhile, the term tint can be generalized to refer to any lighter or darker variation of a color (e.g. tinted windows).[

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an attempt to inflict technical colour theory terms on everyday English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tint comes from Latin **tinctus** "a dyeing," from **tingere** "to dye". Actually you are not colouring, toning or shading your windows you put some sort of UV films so the verb refers to action of putting something that reduce the amount or the type of visible sun light or so called **visible light transmission (VLT)** .We see the light as white hence we use **tint** here.

Answer (score 5):

The words as used in colour theory are jargon with much more precise meanings than when used colloquially. I think the colour theory meaning for tinting came somewhat after the process of tinting glass was arrived at.

Comment: I guess that's what happens when there are no color theorists hanging around the glazier's shop.  Too late now, I think; the phrase has probably stuck.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, many people (including many writers) are unaware of the "add white to tint/add black to shade" distinction; hence we get constructions such as the title of Procol Harum's song, "A Whiter Shade of Pale" (1967). To the credit of popular culture, however, sunglasses are widely known as "shades," not "tints."

The first time I heard the term "tinted window" was in connection with my grandparents' new early-1960s Ford Thunderbird, whose windshield had a 4- or 5-inch band of strikingly blue "tinting" along its upper edge to protect the driver's and front-seat passenger's eyes from the glare of the late-afternoon sun.

I suspect that "tinted window" won out over "shaded window" as a marketing term, for the practical reason that "shaded window" suggests to most people not a window whose glass is to some degree darkened by a film or a chemical treatment, but a window that is protected from admitting direct sunlight by a pull-down shade or blind attached for that purpose or that is prevented from doing so by a physical object (such as a tree or wall) that happens to be nearby and casts a shadow over the window. "Tinted window" is less susceptible to being misconstrued.

Answer (score 0):

I work with windshields for my job and am taking a class in color for web design. I'm not an expert but this is my understanding.

Shading and tinting are both methods of filtering color when it comes to glass. Shading refers to the shadow of light or absents of light. There is no shade if there is no light. The darker a color the less light gets reflected from that color. It's a shadow of light. Tinting refers to the reflecting of light. White is a reflection of light. Tint film absorbs most light making it dark but it does reflect some light giving it a tinge of color. So it is called tint because average people distinguish tint by color. A shade for the windshield is the natural color of the glass. In this sense when light passes through it is left with a shade of color meaning, not all colors make it through.

From a color theory perspective shades emphasis, what color is leftover in a monochromatic color. A darker shade has less color meaning a darker shadow. You are being shaded from more light. Tint emphasizes what color is being reflected within a monochromatic color. In color, theory whiteness is the indication of more colors being reflected.

Tone refers to the saturation of a hue or purity of a hue without changing the hue itself or the luminosity. "A hue is the average wavelength of the perceived color" [1].

Work Cited:

[1] Helfrich, 'User Interface Evaluation and Design'